# Creating Django-WMS - Satellite Raster Images

Tags: python, django, openlayers, raster, wms

I am using Django to connect Openlayers with PostGIS vector data. Everything is on Ubuntu 14.04. But recently I purchased high resolution satellite image which I wanna use as the client's basemap, instead of OSM maps (which I was using till now).

Now, I am totally blank as to how and where to start with? I found [this](https://github.com/geodesign/django-raster) and [this](http://django-wms.readthedocs.org/en/v0.1.11/index.html) to be an starting point.

Till now, I have installed `django-raster` and included `raster` app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section in Django settings.

In my default PostGIS Db I can see `raster_rasterlayer`, `raster_rasterlayermetadata` and 'raster_rastertile' tables, added because of the above `raster` app. But I have no idea now how to populate these tables and then how to connect these table via `views` to the `urls`.

Whatever done by me further was mere hit-n-trial. Kindly guide me what to do now so that in the end I can use these satellite images in the openlayers to create basemap.

**UPDATE 1**:

Logging in into the `admin interface` is letting me to upload raster images into my `raster` app, which I have installed into my `INSTALLED_APPS` section in settings. I am setting `Datatype` to *Continuous*, `Srid` to *4326* `Nodata` to *-9999* in my `admin interface`. But clicking the save button is throwing me `AttributeError at /admin/raster/rasterlayer/add/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetNoDataValue'` error. Kindly help me to fix this up.

Comment: An option would be to install Geoserver and serve it from that.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Thanks. I was using GeoServer an year ago. But since I have switched altogether to Django, I dont wanna use it again. I am sure there must be some way, but unfortunately it's getting hard to figure out how!

Comment: It seems django-raster (which I've never used, so can't really help) doesn't have a urls.py. So you can import raster data into the database using the admin interface, and it will create tiles in the database, and then leaves it up to you to write Django views that implement a TMS service to serve them.

Comment: Thx. I was also trying that but I dunno why but visiting `http://localhost:8083/admin` is throwing me 'TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/login/' error! Strange! The error.log is showing `RuntimeError: response has not been started`. Any Idea?

Comment: I think I had some issue since I copy pasted my whole project from some other dir. Anyways, making a new Django project is working fine except the above stated error message, I have mentioned in the questions UPDATE section

Comment: SetNoDataValue is a GDAL function. It's trying to call that on None, which is what gdal.Open returns if it can't open a file. What's the format of the file you uploaded? Is it something GDAL can open?

Comment: I am using GeoTiff file (3 band satellite image). It must be supported by GDAL.

Comment: Well, hard to tell from here then what the problem is, sorry...

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance. I'll do some troubleshooting and will let you know.